# Redirect user if using proxy or vpn services web

Tags: .htaccess, vpn

I need advice how can I redirect user to my `"custom.html"` page and inform them that they are using vpn service or proxies.
I wish my code work just like this site: https://awebanalysis.com/en/ip-proxy-checker/
Screen detection shows that I use VPN]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Fvv4.png

I'mdoing this because there is a live chat in my website and I can ban only IP and there is a guy who come to my site every day few times with different IP from different VPNs and insulting me and makes jokes. So if he will come with real IP since he wont be able to load my index.html if using proxies or vpn I will caught his IP.

I added this code to my `.htaccess` file but it allow me to vist if Im under vpn or proxies.

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^products\/product\-01\/category\-id\-001\-abc$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/product\-01\-category\.html" [R=301,L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA}                 !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED}           !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR}     !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION}    !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION}   !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP}      !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^146\.70\.
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

Order Allow,Deny
Deny from 85.31.0.
Deny from 146.70.46.
Deny from 107.181.177.
Deny from 122.161.53.
Deny from wiredns.net
Deny from datapacket.com
Deny from 154.47.30.
Deny from 137.59.145.
DEny from 89.46.62.
Deny from lightspeed.wepbfl.sbcglobal.net
Allow from all
```

Comment: And even if you are able to identify "his IP", then what? Are you going to sue him? Get serious ...

Comment: The question is why people can chat on your site apparently without being registered, so without you having any idea who they are?

Comment: Please keep in mind that for many people VPNs and proxies are very important tools to get around haressment by official sites.

Comment: _"and inform them that they are using vpn service or proxies"_ - thanks, but I already know when I do.